# Saving a Draft takes very long in iphone inApp Email

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, iphone-sdk-4.1

I am using MFMailComposeViewController to sent email from my App. It takes around 4 seconds to save a draft but the 'Delete Draft' button completes the task instantly.Both options work fine in simulator but not in my Iphone 3GS running on iOS4.1.

I  tried a few apps from App store  and they also exhibits the same lag while saving the drafts but this is not the case when using iphone's default mail app. Anyone else seeing the same issue? Appreciate if anyone can share a solution or work around.

Comment: Same lag here in my in-app mail. You are not alone. :-)

Comment: Same issue happens on Iphone4 running on 4.2.1. But the strange thing is that not everybody having the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also on a 3GS, 4.1 and I do not experience the lag you mention. `Have you tried a fresh restore of your device or maybe upgrade to 4.2.1`?

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to know whether it is an isolated case.